# Select box with typing feature?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want a select box in html page where is the option are selected from database. User can also type in same box and the input is added to database.

I only figured how to do in two separate boxes bus I want to do in single box

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2">Category</td>
        <td class="style2">
            <select name="category1" style="width: 123px">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "select * from category";
                    //echo $sql;
                    $tbl = mysql_query($sql);
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tbl))
                    { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['category'];?>">
                            <?php echo $row['category'];?>
                        </option></select>
                    <?php } 
                ?>
        </td>
        <td class="style2">
            <input name="category2" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Something like **[this](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)**?

Comment: using chosen plugin (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) you can select the things from available options. But  you have another requirement, that you need to save the typed data in database. This is not possible by any plugin.

Comment: But these are more for searching purpose, I want a box where a user can either select or type the value to be entered in database

Comment: FYI you're missing the `</select>`

Comment: ohh. so you are telling during serching you need to show options.  When user will click enter button, the data typed by the user will be transferred to backend..
 Like google search ??
 In that case you should not use select box.

Comment: Can you please provide me other options @DineshPatra

Comment: @user3041166 am I right about your requirement ???

Comment: @DineshPatra You are but I need some alternatives

Comment: Use select2 library: https://select2.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

As its some long code, i am unable to put it in comment field. But you can make this type.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <input type="text" id="search-box">
       <div id="results">
       </div>

       <script>
         var dbFetchedData = ["us", "india", "germany"];
         document.getElementById("search-box").onkeyup = function() {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '';
            for (var i = 0; i<dbFetchedData.length; i++) {
                if (dbFetchedData[i] == this.value) {
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    li.innerHTML = dbFetchedData[i];
                    document.getElementById("results").appendChild(li);
                }
            }
         }
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I am storing fetched data in javascript array.

You can add eventlistners to li items, better design. Also you can make the code optimized. I hope from this you got some idea.